# Apache server is running but doesn't open htdocs directory

Tags: php, apache

I have configured the `apache 2.4` server right, I know this because it was running but I accidentally moved the php folder and then I tried to restart the apache server and now the apache server can't start again. I'm not using any `WAMPP`, `XAMPP` or any similar packages, I've cleaned the cache I don't know what to do and I'm kind of a newbie in this

On CMD this is what say when I run `httpd.exe -k start` :

```
(OS 10048) Usually only one socket address (protocol / network address / port) is allowed. : 
AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Comment: check/read your httpd.conf or vhost.conf or or to find out what is your document root

Comment: my document root is in htdocs i didn't change nothing in the conf document I just moved the php folder

Comment: what did you mean with moved the php folder? what is the index option of your htdocs folder?

Comment: now can't even start the apache server tried to restart it, it stopped and now it can't start again

Comment: check your error log and fix your config

Comment: Windows could not start the Apache2.4 on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Micorsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1

Comment: check APACHE ERROR LOG FILE

Answer (score 0):

open your file /conf/httpd.conf in apache folder(folder you have been installed your apache)
find the key word: DocumentRoot
you will see:
DocumentRoot "Path_"

Replace "Path_"  to your folder contain your source code
Restart your apache
good look

Comment: I stopped the apache server but now I can't start it again

Comment: make sure you have exits the "Path_" folder in your computer, if the folder is not exits apache could not start.

Comment: exits? i don't know what you mean by exits

Comment: after you change to a new folder, make sure the new folder have created in your computer
example: i change DocumentRoot  to "D:/workplace" i will go to D and create folder "workplace" --> after that restart apache

Comment: i've done that i changed my DocumentRoot, I tried to restart apache, it stopped and it can't start again

Comment: can you show your error on your question that help us to help you easier

Answer (score 0):

Check apache log file available at /etc/apache2/logs in case it's linux debian based system or /apache/logs in case of a local windows installation. Report the error here and then we can take a look at the exact problem.

Comment: (OS 10048) Usually only one socket address (protocol / network address / port) is allowed. : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Comment: Then your port 80 is blocked by some already running application on port 80. I would recommend restarting the system instead of finding the service and shutting it down. Restart will close the running service at port 80 and then you can start the server again. Or may be you are running multiple apache servers, then you have to shut one of them down before starting another instance.